# Using Crystal Report For Windows Application by Using Data Set for Data

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports-2008

I,m Using Crystal Report in Windows Application and In this I Created a Data Set to fetch Data from the Database but I Don't Know How to Pass parameter in Data Set....
Any One can Tell me that How to Pass Parameter to Data Set for Using it in Crystal Report.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to fill in the data into the sub-reports.

```
foreach (ReportDocument subDoc in Report.Subreports)
{
     subDoc.SetDataSource(ReportDataSet);
}
```